# issue with dilation in scikit-image

Tags: type-conversion, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

I have this image of some edges:

[image: edges]

I managed to link disconnected white edges, skeletonize, dilate a bit the edges, crop, and label the complement, all using morphological operations in scikit-image.

Below is the resulting cropped and labeled image. Colorbar added to show range.
[image]

Now I would like to use dilation again to eliminate the black edges (I know the thickness since I previously dilated the skeleton using `disk(3)`.

I tried `dilated = dilation(cropped, disk(4))`

but I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\...\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py:103: 
UserWarning: Possible sign loss when converting negative image of type int32 to positive image of type uint8.
"%s to positive image of type %s." % (dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj))

C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\dtype.py:107: 
UserWarning: Possible precision loss when converting from int32 to uint8
"%s to %s" % (dtypeobj_in, dtypeobj))
```

I am not sure I understand. Since the range is 0-4 I expect no negative values. If I run `print cropped.min(), cropped.max()` I get `0 4`

Can anyone suggest what the problem is and if there is any way around it?

Comment: That's only a warning, and it occurs because the data-type of your array is int32 and whatever algorithm is running is converting it to a postive-only data type.  You can fix it by converting your array's dtype to np.uint32 or np.uint64.